# how to find <ul> within <li> then add class to <li>

Tags: jquery, html, dom-traversal

```
<ul>
<li>nav</li>
<li>nav</li>
<li>nav</li>
<li class="how do i addClass here">nav "how to addClass with in this li"
 <ul>
     <li>nav</li>
     <li>nav</li>
     <li class="how do i addClass here">nav "how to addClass with in this li"
          <ul>
             <li>nav</li>
             <li>nav</li>
             <li>nav</li>
         </ul>
     </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: How to ask questions on StackOverflow - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: You're missing a closing `</li>` tag in there.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul').parent('li').addClass('someclass');
```

Select all the `<ul>` elements, then [do `.parent('li')`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/). This will *only* select the immediate parent element *if* it is a `<li>` element. Then [use `.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add the class.

This uses a valid CSS selector, which is a good thing for performance in browsers that support `querySelectorAll`.

Browsers that don't support it should perform fast as well, since jQuery likely does a `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: @user: You're welcome. Please remember to "accept" this answer if it was helpful by clicking the large checkmark to the left of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("li:has(ul)").each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("<YOUR_CLASS_NAME>")
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body ul:nth-child(1) li:nth-child(4)').addClass('test').find('ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass('test2');
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ps8AA/